# How do I multiply SQL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

## TableA

```
ID       Value  
1        "10,20"  
2        "101,102,103"  
3        "50,60"  
4        "100,200,300"  
5        "81,82,83,84"
```

I want this:

## TableB

```
ID       Value  
1        10  
1        20  
2        101  
2        102  
2        103  
3        50  
3        60  
4        100  
4        200  
4        300  
5        81  
5        82  
5        83  
5        84
```

I'm using SQL Server V18, so I have access to the built-in `STRING_SPLIT()` function, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something?  You seem to know to use `string_split()` and there isn't any other complication as far as I can see:

```
select t.id, s.value
from t cross apply
     string_split(value, ',') s;
```

You can use `insert` or `into` to put the data in another table.

If the double quotes are actually part of the value, you can get rid of them:

```
string_split(replace(value, '"', ''), ',')
```

Comment: No, the double quotes are not part of the data, I just wanted to point out that the data was string/nvarchar type.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but where does the term "s.value" dome from?  It seems to have nothing to do with my column names. If I change my column names from "value" to "widget", I still need to select "s.value".

Comment: @Joe . . . `string_split()` returns a table with one column called `value`.  The `s` is assigned as the table alias for that result.  Hence, `s.value` is the element returned by `string_split()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.